# If statement not working as expected

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

Im currently coding the game snake. And to be short, im having an issue regarding an if-statement. The part thats giving me trouble is a method for checking wether or not the snake is colliding with itself.

The if statement looks like this:

```
public void checkCol(){
    for(int i = 0; i < snake.getLength(); i++){
        if((snake.getXPosArray()[snake.getLength() - 1] == snake.getXPosArray()[i])
                && (snake.getYPosArray()[snake.getLength() - 1] == snake.getYPosArray()[i])){
            gameOver();
        }

    }
}
```

Bear with me on the wall of text here. What im trying to say with this code is: If the head of the snake has the same coordinates as any other part of the snakes body, its gameover.

Initially the snakes length is 3, and is controlled by an array of coordinates. So the first round in the loop will check if:

```
xPos[2] == xPos[0] and the same with yPos[2] == yPos[0]
xPos[2] = 88 , xPos[0] = 66 , yPos[2] = 55 , yPos[0] = 55.
```

The snake stops immidiately when i run the program. Wich is wierd, because i checked the values the method will get. The values shown over is the values that my if statement checks. Now i believe that 88 and 66 is not equal to eachother.

I looked around on the forum for a better explanation of the && operator, and a post told me that && only checks both statements if the first is true. And a single & will check if both arguments are true. But i got the same result with & and &&.

Am i overlooking something silly here? am i to tired? Can you people see anything wrong with this statement? And tell me why it thinks 88 == 66?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you tried printing the values inside the `if`?

Comment: Your idea is good, but you must not compare the head to itself.

Comment: I added a -1 to the length of the array. It works like a charm now. Thanks a bunch! should be going to bed now.. :D
will accept answer when the 5minute limit is over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looping over every cell in the snake, including the head. The head is in the same spot as the head, so the snake eats its own face and dies. Don't include the head in the loop.

Comment: Valuable life lesson: don't eat your own face.

Comment: I added a -1 to the length of the array. It works like a charm now. Thanks a bunch! should be going to bed now.. :D
will accept answer when the 5minute limit is over.

Answer (score 1):

the difference between & and && is that one is a logical operator, the other is a short circuit operator.  [Difference between & and &&](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Also it appears that you will eventually compare the head with the head itself, unless your getLength goes one under the head.

Comment: I added a -1 to the length of the array. It works like a charm now. Thanks a bunch! should be going to bed now.. :D
will accept answer when the 5minute limit is over.

Comment: Check out the link about the & and && as well if you want to understand the difference.  Also make sure to upvote the answers that helped.